# Sitecore SXA not generating optimized.js file

Tags: sxa

Sitecore SXA has stopped generating the optimizedjs file when I upload the scriptminifiled.js
file

Any ideas what could be causing it to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the optimization settings for a specific site:

1. In the Content Editor, navigate to `sitecore/content/<Tenant>/<Site>/Presentation/Page Designs`.
2. In the `Asset Optimization` section, in the `Styles Optimizing Enabled` and `Scripts Optimizing Enabled` fields, to override styles and scripts optimization settings, select:

- Default – to inherit global settings
- Yes – to always enable optimization for this site.
- No – to always disable optimization for this site.

[image]